# Is it possible to attach a VisualForce Page to the Activity Button "Send Email"

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides

In the **Override Standard Button or Link** page for the Activity Button **Send Email** the description says

> You can replace the salesforce.com URL for a standard button or link
>   with a custom s-control or Visualforce Page. Select the custom
>   s-control or Visualforce Page to use in place of the salesforce.com
>   URL for this standard button or link.

However, the **Override With** property only has two options

- No Override (use default)
- Custom S-Control

Is it possible to attach a VisualForce page to this button?

Comment: No answer out there?